# Convert native JavaScript code for a digital clock to jQuery code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have set a simple function so that the local time displays on the webpage. It updates the local time every second so it looks like a digital clock.

I would like to know, what is the JQuery code for the Javascript below?

```
var myVar=setInterval(function(){myTimer()},1000);

function myTimer() {
    var d = new Date();
    document.getElementById("Time").innerHTML = d.toLocaleTimeString();
}
```

I have looked everywhere, but no answer. I don't have the skills do to it myself.
Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need a heavy library?

Comment: There's really only very little change and it won't improve anything significant.

Comment: @Satpal. It is for an assignment. No Javascript is allowed. Only JQuery.

Comment: @Mindrus, Tell the guy who has given you assignment that __jQuery__ is __JavaScript__

Comment: @Satpal. Omg. He is a school teacher. He doesn't even know what he is talking about. I will just put as much JQuery in as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I have no idea why would you like to change this code to Jquery since you will be making it more heavier using jquery (the only thing that can be changed to jquery is document.getElementById which is slower that the actual javascript code )** but anyways,

```
   var myVar=setInterval(function(){myTimer()},1000);

   function myTimer() {
      var d = new Date();
      $("#Time").html(d.toLocaleTimeString());
   }
```

Comment: Thanks bro. It's for an assignment.:3

Answer (score 0):

Plain old javascript (pojs) is always more efficient if you can be bothered to learn/write it.

jQuery is a convenience that allows you to "write less, do more" but never more efficiently.

But to answer the question, there's not much to do.

Change

```
document.getElementById("Time").innerHTML = d.toLocaleTimeString();
```

to :

```
$("#Time").html(d.toLocaleTimeString());
```

You can also change :

```
var myVar = setInterval(function(){ myTimer() }, 1000);
```

to :

```
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);
```

but that's just better javascript, not jQuery.

Comment: Thanks. It is for an assignment. We aren't allowed to use Javascript for some unknown reason. Only JQuery is allowed.

Comment: Totally wacky, everyone should learn javascript first, imo. Of course, if it's a jQuery course that's different.

Comment: First things to learn are [jQuery's selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: `We aren't allowed to use Javascript for some unknown reason` . `setInterval()` is a javascript function and you cannot change that to JQUERY AT ALL

Comment: Yes, jQuery *is* javascript, not an independent language, so you can't write jQuery without writing js - and some js expressions simply don't have a jQuery equivalent.

Comment: lol. JQuery is merely a more efficent way to type then Javascript.

Comment: Sort of. A better statement would be "JQuery is merely a way to achieve more with Javascript, while writing less source code".

Comment: Saying "you can't just JavaScript, just jQuery" is like saying "you can't use words, just English"